# How to make an error listener for Saxon errors in s9api?

Tags: java, saxon, s9api

I'm trying to listen to the errors in s9api going to stdout, but I'm not finding a good working example.  Here's what I have:

```
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
compiler.setErrorListener((ErrorListener) new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
           System.out.println("WARNING");       
        }

        @Override
        public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
           System.out.println("ERROR");         
        }

        @Override
        public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
           System.out.println("FATAL");         
        }
});
```

Eclipse wants to add `import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;`, but that's JAXP and not s9api, so is not working.  I'm missing something to get this working for s9api.  Any suggestions?

--Edit--

Here's the full test case isolated.  Running this using Saxon 9.9.

```
package com.test;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmDestination;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmNode;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

@WebServlet("/test")

public class test extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting test");       
        String test = "default";
        
        try {   
            Processor processor = new Processor(true);
            XsltCompiler c1 = processor.newXsltCompiler();
            c1.setErrorListener((ErrorListener) new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
                   System.out.println("WARNING");       
                }

                @Override
                public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
                   System.out.println("ERROR");         
                }

                @Override
                public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
                   System.out.println("FATAL");         
                }
            });
            String xsltString = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"3.0\">\n"
                    + "    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\n"
                    + "        <xsl:message terminate=\"yes\">This is a runtime error message</xsl:message>\n"
                    + "        <error test=\"here\"/>\n"
                    + "    </xsl:template>\n"
                    + "</xsl:stylesheet>";

            XsltExecutable s1 = c1.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltString)));
            Xslt30Transformer t1 = s1.load30();
            XdmNode rootNode = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<root/>")));
            XdmDestination xdm = new XdmDestination();
            t1.applyTemplates(rootNode, xdm);
            test = xdm.getXdmNode().children().iterator().next().getAttributeValue(new QName("test"));
        } catch (Exception err) {
            String errorBody = "";
            errorBody += req.getRequestURL().toString() + "\n";
            errorBody += "\n";
            errorBody += err.getCause() + "\n";
            errorBody += err.toString() + "\n";
            errorBody += "\n";
            for (StackTraceElement element : err.getStackTrace()) {
                errorBody += element.toString() + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println(errorBody);       
        }
        
        res.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(req.getContextPath()).append(" "+test);
    }

}
```

Here is what is printed to stdout.  `System.out.println("FATAL")` is not executed.

```
Starting test
This is a runtime error message
Error on line 3 column 38 
  XTMM9000: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in 
  In template rule with match="/" on line 2 of 
http://localhost:8090/tmm/test

net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TerminationException: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in 
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in 

net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer.applyTemplates(Xslt30Transformer.java:451)
com.winequest.test.doGet(test.java:63)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1410)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:170)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:192)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:51)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.produce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:193)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

--Edit #2--

I've upgraded from Saxon 9.9.1 PE to 11.6 PE, in order to implement ErrorReporter, per the suggestions given here.  I'm still not able to get it to intercept and display anything.  Here's my test case:

```
package com.winequest;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmDestination;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmNode;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Xslt30Transformer;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

@WebServlet("/test")

public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting test");       
        String test = "default";
        
        try {   
            Processor processor = new Processor(true);
            XsltCompiler c1 = processor.newXsltCompiler();
            c1.setErrorReporter((error) -> System.out.println("Lambda Error: " + error.getMessage()));
            String xsltString = "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"3.0\">\n"
                    + "    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\n"
                    + "        <xsl:message terminate=\"yes\">This is a runtime error message</xsl:message>\n"
                    + "        <error test=\"here\"/>\n"
                    + "    </xsl:template>\n"
                    + "</xsl:stylesheet>";

            XsltExecutable s1 = c1.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltString)));
            Xslt30Transformer t1 = s1.load30();
            XdmNode rootNode = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<root/>")));
            XdmDestination xdm = new XdmDestination();
            t1.applyTemplates(rootNode, xdm);
            test = xdm.getXdmNode().children().iterator().next().getAttributeValue(new QName("test"));
        } catch (Exception err) {
            String errorBody = "";
            errorBody += req.getRequestURL().toString() + "\n";
            errorBody += "\n";
            errorBody += err.getCause() + "\n";
            errorBody += err.toString() + "\n";
            errorBody += "\n";
            System.out.println(errorBody);       
        }
        
        res.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(req.getContextPath()).append(" "+test);
    }

}
```

And the console output:

```
Starting test
This is a runtime error message
Error on line 3 column 38 
  XTMM9000  Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in 
  In template rule with match="/" on line 2 of 
http://localhost:8090/tmm/test

net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TerminationException: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in 
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 3 in
```

The code `System.out.println("Lambda Error: " + error.getMessage())` is not executed, as this does not appear in the output.  So it does appear to be something unrelated to ErrorListener vs ErrorReporter.  Any ideas?

--EDIT--

I figured out the issue.  <xsl:message terminate="yes"> does not trigger the lambda function as it's not an error.  <xsl:bogusmessage terminate="yes"> is a compilation error, and does trigger the lambda function.  It's because the latter is a static error or warning encountered during a compilation, and the former is not.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean exactly? For 9.9 the method indeed takes a `javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener`: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#setErrorListener-javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener-

Comment: It means none of the text is printed to System.out

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with the code you have shown us. Which means, frustratingly for all of us, that there is something wrong with the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: So I'll isolate it into a complete test case.  I've edited the question with the full case.

Comment: In my test using 12.x the  evaluation of`xsl:message terminate="yes"` was reported to the `ErrorListener.fatalError()` callback.

Comment: OK, so looks like I'll have to migrate to 12.3.  I'll just need to work through the things that broke.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#setErrorReporter(net.sf.saxon.lib.ErrorReporter) and implement https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/ErrorReporter.html.

Comment: I should have stated version. I'm still on 9.9. That doesn't implement setErrorReporter().  Which may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which version of Saxon you are using.

In recent versions the s9api XsltCompiler does have the method `XsltCompiler.setErrorListener()` (taking a JAXP ErrorListener as the argument), but the method has been deprecated since Saxon 10, which is probably what Eclipse is complaining about.

The replacement method is `XsltCompiler.setErrorReporter()`, which is easier to use because the `ErrorReporter` is a functional interface, so you can call it with a lambda expression or method reference, for example

`XsltCompiler.setErrorReporter(err -> myLogger.display(err));`

The new design has other benefits: the error object is no longer an exception, which means it doesn't carry an expensive stack trace, and the callback no longer declared a checked exception, which makes it clearer that the error reporter isn't expected to fail.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have stated version.  I'm still on 9.9, as it's been solid.  That doesn't implement setErrorReporter().

Comment: I've purchased 12.3 PE, but a lot of my XSL code broke when running on the latest.  So that will be some effort to transition that I'll investigate later.  In the meantime, let's see if we can get 9.9 working.

Comment: I could not get 12.3 PE installed because of an SQL bug.  But I was able install 11.6 PE, in order to implement ErrorReporter.  As with ErrorListener, I am not able to get the ErrorReporter to execute properly.  I'll update the question with the updated test case.